# Channel error "AMQ9638: SSL communications error for channel"

Tags: ibm-mq

I am getting frequent error for our channels as below

```
=======
AMQ9638: SSL communications error for channel 'xxxx'.

EXPLANATION:
An unexpected SSL communications error occurred for a channel, as reported in
the preceding messages. The channel is 'xxxx'; in some cases its
name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'. The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Investigate the problem reported in the preceding messages. Review the local
and remote console logs for reports of network errors. Correct the errors and
restart the channel.
=======
```

As verified,

1. SSL Certificate is valid for sender and receiver
2. No changes performed with ssl key.kdb

Found following error on remote side

```
=======
AMQ9716E: Remote SSL certificate revocation status check failed for channel
'????'.

EXPLANATION:
IBM MQ failed to determine the revocation status of the remote SSL certificate
for one of the following reasons:
(a) The channel was unable to contact any of the CRL servers or OCSP responders
  for the certificate.
(b) None of the OCSP responders contacted knows the revocation status of the
  certificate.
(c) An OCSP response was received, but the digital signature of the response
  could not be verified.

 

The details of the certificate in question are
'xxxxx'.

The channel name is '????'. In some cases the channel name cannot be determined
and so is shown as '????'. The channel did not start.

IBM MQ does not allow the channel to start unless the certificate revocation
status can be determined.
ACTION:
If the certificate contains an AuthorityInfoAccess extension, ensure that the
OCSP server named in the certificate extension is available and is correctly
configured.

If the certificate contains a CrlDistributionPoint extension, ensure that the
CRL server named in the certificate extension is available and is correctly
configured.

If you have specified any CRL or OCSP servers to IBM MQ, check that those
servers are available and are correctly configured.

Ensure that the local key repository has the necessary SSL certificates to
verify the digital signature of the response from the OCSP server.

AMQ9999E: Channel '????' to host 'xxxx' ended abnormally.
=======
```

qm.ini file contains below parameters also under ssl stanza

```
   OCSPAuthentication=OPTIONAL
   OCSPCheckExtensions=NO
```

Not sure how to fix this problem. Could some one please help here ?

tried `refresh security type(SSL)`, but didn't worked too

```
qm.ini file data

#*******************************************************************#$
#* Module Name: qm.ini                                             *#$
#* Type       : IBM MQ queue manager configuration file            *#$
#  Function   : Define the configuration of a single queue manager *#$
#*                                                                 *#$
#*******************************************************************#$
#* Notes      :                                                    *#$
#* 1) This file defines the configuration of the queue manager     *#$
#*                                                                 *#$
#*******************************************************************#$
ExitPath:$
   ExitsDefaultPath=/var/mqm/exits$
   ExitsDefaultPath64=/var/mqm/exits64$
#*                                                                 *#$
#*                                                                 *#$
Log:$
   LogPrimaryFiles=10$
   LogSecondaryFiles=10$
   LogFilePages=32768$
   LogType=LINEAR$
   LogBufferPages=2048$
   LogPath=/var/mqm/log/<QM Name>/$
   LogWriteIntegrity=TripleWrite$
   LogManagement=Automatic$
Service:$
   Name=AuthorizationService$
   EntryPoints=14$
ServiceComponent:$
   Service=AuthorizationService$
   Name=MQSeries.UNIX.auth.service$
   Module=amqzfu$
   ComponentDataSize=0$
TCP:$
   KeepAlive=Yes$
   ListenerBacklog=400$
   SndBuffSize=0$
   RcvBuffSize=0$
   RcvSndBuffSize=0$
   RcvRcvBuffSize=0$
   ClntSndBuffSize=0$
   ClntRcvBuffSize=0$
   SvrSndBuffSize=0$
   SvrRcvBuffSize=0$
Channels:$
   ChlauthEarlyAdopt=Y$
   MaxChannels=400$
   StopEvent=ALWAYS$
   AdoptNewMCA=ALL$
   AdoptNewMCATimeOut=60$
   AdoptNewMCACheck=ALL$
$
QMErrorLog:$
   ErrorLogSize=4194304$
#   ExcludeMessage=7234$
   SuppressMessage=9001,9002,9202$
   SuppressInterval=30$
$
# PMR (pub/sub) 33868,070,724 zisSPIInquirePubSubStatus rc=MQRC_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER$
#Connection:$
#   DefaultBindTYPE=ISOLATED$
SSL:$
   MinimumRSAKeySize=2048$
   OCSPAuthentication=OPTIONAL$
   OCSPCheckExtensions=NO$
   AllowWeakCipherSpec=TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256$
$
#ApiExitLocal:$
#   Name=MessageTracker$
#   Sequence=100$
#   Function=EntryPoint$
#   Module=mtxapi$
$
# Special Tuning for Queue creation. Needs qmgr restart$
TuningParameters:$
#   DefaultQBufferSize=256000$
   TolerateRepositoryFailure=TRUE$
$
```

```
Name:        IBM MQ
Version:     9.3.0.5
Level:       p930-005-230413
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    IBM MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Linux 4.12.14-122.159-default
O/S Details: SLES 12-SP5
InstName:    Installation2
InstDesc:
Primary:     Yes
InstPath:    /opt/mqm930
DataPath:    /var/mqm
MaxCmdLevel: 930
LicenseType: Production

Name:        IBM MQ
Version:     9.1.0.8
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:
InstPath:    /opt/mqm910
Primary:     No
```

Comment: If this is on Linux or AIX try `cat -vte qm.ini` look for and extra control characters or trailing spaces or extra lines.   Note the output will show the end of line character as a `$` character and this can be ignored. Can you please edit your question and add the output of ` dspmqver` and the `qm.ini` file.

Comment: @JoshMc - I have updated the qm.ini file and dspmqver output. Looks like qm.ini file also fine.

Comment: As per https://colinpaice.blog/amq9716e-remote-ssl-certificate-revocation-status-check-failed-for-channel/ is there a CERTLABEL on the the channel definition?

Answer (score 4):

Something to bear in mind with certificate revocation checks within queue managers is that there are actually two mechanisms that the queue manager will use. The first is OCSP, which you have already disabled / set to optional, so the queue manager will not cause these errors due to OCSP. However, I cannot see the second mechanism mentioned in your qm.ini.

That second mechanism is called CDPCheckExtensions, short for CRL Distribution Point Check Extensions. This is enabled by default, and means the queue manager will consult the CRL Distribution Points defined in the certificate configured at either the channel or queue manager levels (the channel level is more specific, and is selected if defined, otherwise the queue manager's certificate is used).

Relevant docs for your version: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=qmini-ssl-stanza-file

As a diagnostic measure, I would try disabling CDPCheckExtensions by setting `CDPCheckExtensions=NO` in the ssl stanza of the qm.ini and then restart the queue manager. But do be aware, with both CRLs *and* OCSP disabled, you are completely unable to verify if a certificate has been revoked. This creates a considerable security risk and is therefore strongly *not recommended*, especially in production environments.

Edit: On second inspection of the docs, it is not immediately clear as to whether CDPCheckExtensions is enabled by default. The docs have contradicting information on that specific parameter as shown below:

```
CDPCheckExtensions=YES|NO (default)

    Specifies whether TLS channels on this queue manager try to check CDP servers that are named in CrlDistributionPoint certificate extensions.

    - YES (default) : TLS channels try to check CDP servers to determine whether a digital certificate is revoked.
    - NO: TLS channels do not try to check CDP servers. This value is the default.
```

Given that this is the only other setting that would cause the error you're seeing, I'd still recommend disabling it as a diagnostic test.

Edit 2: Another idea I just had, given that there's two installations of IBM MQ running here... is it possible that the queue manager was cloned when it was moved to 9.3? I'm wondering if the running queue manager is not using the qm.ini OP has provided... to rule this out is fairly trivial, a simple `DISPLAY QMGR CMDLEVEL` inside runmqsc would be sufficient to prove which installation the queue manager is using.

Comment: @JoshMc - It works with addition of "CDPCheckExtensions=NO" in the qm.ini file. I see the channel is running fine now.

Comment: Since this was the answer that solved the issue, could you please mark it as accepted? :)